# str_replace number shenanigans

Tags: php, str-replace

Alright, I'm currently stumped by this.

I have this code:

```
ECHO $CHECKVOTINGROW[VOTECHOICES];  
ECHO $STRREPLACECHECKVOTECHOICES = STR_REPLACE("U","",$CHECKVOTINGROW[VOTECHOICES])
```

output UUUSSS1

So the string replace of U's in UUUSSS is returning 1 instead of SSS.

What silly thing am I missing with this?

Edit:

$CHECKVOTINGROW[VOTECHOICES] ORIGINAL VALUE IS UUUSSS

I flagged this for removal, thanks for helping.  Must be a problem somewhere else causing problems.  I won't subject people to more code for parsing.  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure that you check it carefully? http://3v4l.org/MUfig

Comment: @SAM, Please specify the value of `$CHECKVOTINGROW[VOTECHOICES]`

Comment: @CollinJSimpson He echoes it in the program and showed the output.

Comment: Please adopt a more contemporary coding style. All-uppercase variable names and unquoted array keys are just as uncommon nowadays as all-uppercase function calls.

Comment: @mario  Thanks but I'll keep my coding style the way it is.

Comment: PLEASE STOP SHOUTING!

Comment: Are you sure the program doesn't have `==` instead of `=` in the second line?

Comment: @Barmar - I tried changing `=` to `==` but still couldn't get it to produce a `1` in the output. Not sure how php would handle an uninitialized variable in a comparison... but maybe SAM had it initialized earlier in the code?

Comment: @Floris I'm guessing that he used `==` and somehow already initialized the variable. I can't think of any other way he could be getting this output.

Comment: All of these are incorrect.

Comment: Shocker, snarky little Barmar can't think of a correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are echoing the result of the assignment operation:

```
ECHO $STRREPLACECHECKVOTECHOICES = STR_REPLACE("U","",$CHECKVOTINGROW[VOTECHOICES])
```

You want this:

```
$STRREPLACECHECKVOTECHOICES = STR_REPLACE("U","",$CHECKVOTINGROW[VOTECHOICES]);
ECHO $STRREPLACECHECKVOTECHOICES;
```

Echoing the result of an assignment operation outputs the value that was assigned. The output you provided is inconsistent with what the *real* output of that command should be:

```
UUUSSSSSSSS
```

Check your code. Did you mispell `==` as `=`? If the equals operation is successful (`True`), it makes sense that the result might get cast to `1` (1 is true, 0 is false), resulting in your output `UUUSSS1`. FYI: My PHP doesn't seem to cast `True` to `1`, but yours might.

PS: That coding style hurts my eyes.

Comment: The result of an assignment is the value that was assigned, so why should that cause a problem?

Comment: Same result either way for me.

Comment: I presume there was a typo, then? `1` was likely casted from `True`. How else could the `1` sneak in there?

Comment: @CollinJSimpson you are as puzzled as I am...

Comment: @SAM - did this actually solve your problem? "Thanks for trying" sounds more like a consolation prize.

Comment: @CollinJSimpson I think you were probably right about the 1 being from True.  Helped me to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
<?php
$ch="UUUSSS";
echo $ch."\n";
$STR = STR_REPLACE("U","",$ch);
echo $STR."\n";
?>
```

It produces

```
UUUSSS
SSS
```

As expected.

As written, your code is echoing an assignment... not sure that is a good idea (although it's not illegal). Keep things readable - it's usually a good idea. "one thing per line of code".

**EDIT** I did find a way to generate your output:

```
<?php
$ch="UUUSSS";
echo $ch;
$STR = "SSS";
echo $STR == STR_REPLACE("U","",$ch);
echo "\n";
?>
```

This generates exactly

```
UUUSSS1
```

As you observed. So the question remains: are you sure the code that is giving you trouble is exactly the code as written?

Note - using a short variable name in an example is usually a good idea...

Comment: The echoing is only temporary to try to give me an idea of what was going on.